# Split XML stream by XML documents

Tags: java, xml, sax, stax

I have a stream of schemaless XML documents like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message id="1">
    <text>aaaaaaa</text>
</message>
<kuku>
    bbbbb
</kuku>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<other_message id="3">
    <text>ccccc</text>
</other_message>
```

Need to parse documents is stream mode. 
The solution to wrap the stream by single root XML element doesn't work because StAX fails when it meets `<?xml ... ?>` element inside the document. But it can be used if I will be able to skip this element in input stream.

All the documents can be different, so there is no common `end_document` XML element.

Comment: What exactly do you consider an "XML document"? In the sense of the definition of the XML spec you would need to have a single root element that contains all other elements. That doesn't seem to be the case even for your first fragment which has `message` and `kuku` at the top level.

Comment: You want to use SAX or StAX ? They are essentially different model; your question is tagged with both.

Comment: Is it ensured that any XML declaration (`<?xml version="1.0" ...?>`) is on a line of its own? XQuery 3 or XSLT 3 using `unparsed-text-lines` and `xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with` in XSLT or a tumbling window in XQuery  to identify fragments and then `parse-xml-fragment` on each group `string-join()`ed should at least allow to split input like that.

Comment: @Ironluca both of them fail when meet the second root element or XML parsing instruction ```<?...?>```

Comment: @MartinHonnen no, there is no any splitter defined, there is only one condition: current root element was closed, then starts next document.

Comment: @PavelLeonov, as observed by you, either you filter the declarations out of the stream or follow some variation of Dr. Kay's suggestion. There would be no other meachnism.

Comment: Does that sample in the question represent a stream of two or of three documents?

Comment: @MartinHonnen yes, this is a stream of many documents.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of doing this 100% reliably. You can't do it using an XML parser because it will report an error when it sees the second XML declaration, and there's no way of recovering from that error. So you have to do it using your own "pre-parsing", and there is always a risk that your pre-parsing will recognize something that looks like an XML declaration, but isn't, because (for example) it's within the body of an XML comment or CDATA section. But that's probably the best you can do. The elegant way of doing it is probably to write an implementation of InputStream that delivers an Iterable sequence of InputStreams, and then loop over this iterable passing each one to the XML parser in turn. Alternatively your suggestion of filtering out the XML declarations (and adding an outer wrapping start tag and end tag) would also work.

Better, encourage the person who supplied this data that they're doing it wrong.

Comment: Adding an outer wrapping start tag and end tag doesn't work because XML parser will find XML parsing instruction of inner document in the body (```<? ... ?>```)

Comment: I have not found a way to ignore them in the parser.
The dirty solution is to filter the elements in the own InputStream:

Comment: Yes, it's dirty input so the only solution is going to be dirty. (I think your comments are saying exactly what I said in my answer, actually)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but it's somehow ugly and hackish. You can use StAX and count the opening and closing element tags. Increase the counter on an opening tag and decrease at a closing tag. When you reach `0` you know you have completely read the root element. Use the [`getLocation()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#getLocation--) method on the `XMLStreamReader` to see how far you have read, specially the [`getCharsetOffset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/Location.html#getCharacterOffset--) method. With the new position/offset from your original source/stream, you can build a new stream with the start point at the next XML declaration. As a proof-of-concept see the following code:

```
String content = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n"+
            "<foobar>\n"+
            "    <bla />\n"+
            "</foobar>\n"+
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ASCII\" ?>\n"+
            "<first with=\"attributes\">\n"+
            "   <second>\n"+
            "       <third />\n"+
            "   </second>\n"+
            "</first>";
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes());
XMLStreamReader xmlReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(stream);
int nestingCounter = 0;
int characterOffset = 0;
while(xmlReader.hasNext()) {
    int event = xmlReader.next();
    characterOffset = xmlReader.getLocation().getCharacterOffset();
    if (event == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
        nestingCounter++;
    }
    if (event == XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT) {
        nestingCounter--;
    }
    // work with the event/data here
    System.out.println(event);
    if (nestingCounter == 0) {
        break;
    }
}

System.out.println("Second XML");

// build a new stream
content = content.substring(characterOffset).trim();
xmlReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes()));

// now, again...
while(xmlReader.hasNext()) {
    int event = xmlReader.next();
    if (event == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
        nestingCounter++;
    }
    if (event == XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT) {
        nestingCounter--;
    }           
    // work with the event/data here
    System.out.println(event);
    if (nestingCounter == 0) {
        break;
    }
}
```

This will generate the following output (and not throw an exception):

```
1
4
1
2
4
2
Second XML
1
4
1
4
1
2
4
2
4
2
```

Obviously you should use a proper loop and close the streams and readers, this is only a proof-of-concept. Also, you might run in problems when you have [other stuff](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Misc) between the closing tag of the previous root element and the new XML declaration, because you can have this stuff [at the end, but not at the beginning](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-document) of an XML document:

> ### 2.1 Well-Formed XML Documents
>
> ```
> document     ::=      prolog element Misc*
> ```
>
> ### 2.8 Prolog and Document Type Declaration
>
> ```
> Misc         ::=      Comment | PI | S
> ```

Comment: Thanks for answer, POC works fine in case you have String input. Is there any similar solution in case I have not String as input, but InputStream?
I tried to reuse InputStream object with new instance of parser, but it doesn't work because the parser uses buffered reader and current cursor position in the stream (when parsing of first doc is finished) is already somewhere inside next XML doc.

Comment: @PavelLeonov I ran into the same problems. It might be possible to use a `BufferedInputStream()` to go back and forth in the stream using the `reset()` and `skip()` methods with the values provided by `getCharacterOffset()`.